# Appending two arrays of strings into one [BASH]

Tags: bash

Suppose I have two arrays where:

```
a[i] = "space separated string"
b[i] = "22"
```

I want to make a third array so that:

```
c[i]= "${a[i]} ${b[i]}} #appending two string with space between them.
```

Is it possible without loops?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the most inefficient way to do it, but here it is without loops:

```
IFS=$'\n' c=($(paste -d ' ' <(printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${b[@]}")))
```

Of course it only works if there are no newlines in the array elements